# Given a domain that resolves to 2 IPs, is there an error I can return from one of the IPs to let client know to try the other IP?

Tags: tcp, dns, ip

I am aware that if the client cannot reach one IP, it will try the other. I'm talking about the scenario where one IP does respond but it cannot process the connection because for example it has run out of file descriptors so it should return an error letting the client know so it tries the other IP. But I also have read that if the IP responds, no matter what error, the client will treat that as an available server and keep trying to connect to it without trying the other. Surely there must be an error I can return for my scenario right?

Comment: "I am aware that if the client cannot reach one IP, it will try the other. " That depends on the client. What applications are you talking about? Web browsing? Also your question is not about programming, so it is off-topic on this website.

Comment: "Surely there must be an error I can return for my scenario right?" I think your are misunderstanding the classical OSI/Internet stack of layers, and what happens at the IP level, with what happens at other layers on top of it like TCP or HTTP. I guess you are speaking about HTTP, but you don't specify.

Comment: Also as exposed your problem seems very much like an X/Y problem. What exactly are you trying to solve? You shouldn't publish data in the DNS (IP addresses or other stuff) that you know is not working. Why is this IP not working? Is that under your command? What TTLs do you use? Is there some kind of CDN/load balancer (again considering you speak about HTTP, but that would need to be specified) in front of it? Do you control the BGP plane? Etc.

Comment: Initially I was thinking of HTTP, but then I realized how ridiculous that is because I mentioned of file descriptors having run out as the reason for connection not established AFTER the connection was established. So what I actually should be referring to is the TCP/IP layer. If a server can be reached, but a connection cannot be established because of file descriptors having run out, is there a standard behavior on the web browser with regards to which IP it tries reconnection with? That's the question I should've asked in the first place.

Comment: TCP/IP does not have error coming back inside the stream itself. The stream is either open or not. If there is a problem an ICMP message is produced back normally and sent to client, and that message may contain further details (but not wise to count on it), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Control_messages for a list of cases but many are filtered by the network. The TCP/IP state is either open or the server replies back with a close or timeout, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#/media/File:Tcp_state_diagram_fixed_new.svg

Comment: "is there a standard behavior on the web browser with regards to which IP it tries reconnection with?" typically that just looks like a timeout from your description, so the client will wait some time to get a reply and if not, will switch back to alternate means, like another IP address.

Comment: I see .  Thanks.

Comment: What about using a loadbalancer with a health check? Is this something that would work for you?